# Deleting item from recyclerView when certain icon is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have an adapter which has the following lines inside the onCreateParentViewHolder method:

```
    tacho.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("mytag", "notititle es " + notiTitle.getText());
            String[] mytext = notiTitle.getText().toString().replace("\nUpdate", "").replace("\nActualización", "").split(":");
            for(String s: myNotif){
                if(s.contains(mytext[0]) && s.contains(mytext[1]) && s.contains(mytext[2]) && s.contains(mytext[3].replace(" ", "")) ){
                    Log.d("mytag", "Match!");
                    myNotif.remove(s);
                    editor.putStringSet("notifications", myNotif);
                    editor.commit();

                }

            }
        }
    });
```

So this onClickListener works fine. It deletes certain item from the Set at Shared preferences. But I also want to delete the item from my RecyclerView. How can I do this?

My recyclerView loads data from shared preferences, so when I exit the activity and reenter it, it deletes the item, so that works just fine. But the thing is it should also be deleted instantly.

Answer (score 1):

you should remove the item from the adapter which is passed to the recyclerview, then notifyDatasetchanged, like that:

```
YourAdapter.remove(The_Item_That_Should_Be_Removed);
YourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

this should do the job.

Comment: Is there no way to remove from inside the adapter?

Comment: yes you can by making the adapter static, declare your adapter object as "public static", then inside your adapter code, call it and do as i showed you before.